# SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() not throwing expected error in VB.net

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net

```
Me.mycom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Schritte_WegGruppen VALUES (" & SchrittID.ToString & ", " & WegGruppeID.ToString & ", '...')"
Me.mycom.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The above two lines execute perfectly fine in VB .NET, but they throw this exception in C#:

> The statement has ended. Violation of the PRIMARY KEY restriction "PK_Schritte_WegGruppen_ID_Schritte_ID_WegGruppen". A duplicate key can not be inserted into the object "dbo.steps_pathgroups". The double key value is (1, 1).

This exception is totally logical and I get the same exception when I execute this query in SQL Server Management Studio too. I expect an error in the VB code when I run it but I don't get any exception. I do not understand why.

Is there a difference between how `ExecuteNonQuery()` works in VB.Net and C#?

Here is the complete VB code which I'm trying to translate to C#.

```
 Try
        '*** In die Modul Datenbank wechseln ***
        Me.mycom.CommandText = "USE " & ModulDB
        Me.mycom.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Me.mycom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Schritte_WegGruppen VALUES (" & SchrittID.ToString & ", " & WegGruppeID & ", '...')"
        Me.mycom.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Return 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        Me.ErrMess = ex.Message
        Return -1
```

And the translated C# code is here:

```
try 
{
    //*** In die Modul Datenbank wechseln ***
    this.mycom.CommandText = "USE " + ModulDB;
    this.mycom.ExecuteNonQuery();

    this.mycom.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Schritte_WegGruppen VALUES (" + SchrittID.ToString() + ", " + WegGruppeID.ToString() + ", '...')";
    this.mycom.ExecuteNonQuery();

    return 1;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    this.ErrMess = ex.Message;
    return -1;
}
```

I hope my question is clearer now.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `try/catch` estructure in your VB.net code?

Comment: Say it with me... "do", "not", "concatenate", "input", "into", "sql".... seriously, that code is a **massive** SQLI risk. But: in the VB code, do you have any error handling code that could be swallowing the exception?

Comment: you didn't show us the c# code

Comment: The exceptions in C# and VB.NET are handled the same. It would be terrible if that wouldn't be the case. Did you check using the debugger if the exception is really not thrown? Is there some `try`-`catch` anywhere, or the good old `On Error GoTo Fehler`?

Comment: You are inserting different values between VB.Net and C#. If you use MySQL, you can use "REPLACE INTO" instead of "INSERT INTO". Or, as a workaround, delete using the primary key in front of inserting the new line.

Comment: @MarcGravell : taken your point. Will edit that before i finish. Thanks !

Comment: @user2139876 FWIW, I recommend tools like "dapper" for making it trivially easy to parameterize queries without getting bogged down in ADO.NET details; in this case: `Me.mycom.Execute("INSERT INTO Schritte_WegGruppen VALUES (@SchrittID, @WegGruppeID, ...)", new { SchrittID, WegGruppeID, ... });` is all it would take with dapper. It will also avoid query-plan-cache saturation and i18n / l10n issues with converting things to strings; win:win.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Your edit: if you want to change your database, it is much easier to use this: mycon.ChangeDatabase("NEUE_DATENBANK")

Comment: Where do you have that code? In your Form_Load?

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET - or more generally *any* library code - almost always doesn't know or care what language the calling code is using. As such, there are three likely reasons for what you describe:

- the data / system-state is different in your two test cases meaning that it *genuinely isn't erroring* in one case, but is in the other - *because* they are talking about different scenarios
- it is erroring, but you have some surrounding exception-handling code (typically: `try`/`catch` or `On Error`) that is swallowing the exception
- you have made an error translating the code between the two languages, and the actual string you are executing is *different*

Comment: I'm using the exact same database and the same tables. Checked for the final values before the SQL query call and they are identical. In fact, what is bothering me is the SQL query string framed in the VB code fails when I run it directly on the SQL Server management studio and passes in the VB code. This is very strange to me.

Comment: @user2139876 then once again: check the error-handling code that surrounds it. If you simply add `Console.WriteLine("yay, I got here!");` (or similar) after the `ExecuteNonQuery()` - does it *actually get there*?

Comment: Just checked. No, it doesn't. The exception is thrown at `ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: @user2139876 so... it is actually throwing in both cases? then the issue is your exception handling code

Comment: No, I get an exception only in the C# code. VB code runs without an exception and this is the behavior I do not understand.

Comment: @user2139876 and are they both using the exact same connection string? if you are using integrated / windows auth, are they both running as the exact same identity? are you 150% really truly sure that the constructed string is 100% identical?

Answer (score 0):

### Catch ex As Exception

Please replace Catch ex As Exception with Catch ex As SqlException, I had the same problem and now I can catch the exception.